# Pull changes on one bitbucket repo cloned on team foundation server TFS

Tags: git, tfs, version-control, pull

I'm working as a designer on a dev team who have their project code hosted in a Team Foundation Server Versión 15.112.26307.0

They want that I put my HTML/CSS/JS project in a folder on their TFS.

Actually I have my design proyect on a private GIT repo hosted on bitbucket.org.

I've read about [clone a GIT repo on TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/import-git-repository) but couldn't find an answer to my questions:

1. There is a way to pull the changes made in the bitbucket GIT repo on the TFS cloned repo to saty always sync?
2. If not, can I just clone a local copy of the TFS repo (previously cloned from bitbucket) on my computer (git clone http://tfsdevprojectrepo.com/repodir) and then push my changes to the main project on TFS as I do now with the bitbucket project?

Any help or clue about this are wellcome because I can't find anything on google about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to sync TFS git repo with bibucket repo automatically. And based on your situation, the two remote repos have different commit historis. So it’s not necessary to always sync the two repos, but you can pull the changes from bitbucket to TFS from time to time.

I listed the detail steps to pull changes from bitbucket (assume the changes is on bitbucket repo `master` branch) to TFS based on different situations:

- **If the changes need push to a separate branch for TFS repo:**

  ```
  git clone http://tfsdevprojectrepo.com/repodir
  cd repodir
  git remote add upstream <URL for bitbucket repo> -f
  git checkout -b newbranch upstream/master
  git push -u origin newbranch
  ```
- **If the changes need push to a folder (assume the folder name is `project1`) of an existing TFS branch:**

  ```
  git clone http://tfsdevprojectrepo.com/repodir
  cd repodir
  git remote add upstream <URL for bitbucket repo> -f
  # If the folder project1 not exist, use mkdir project1 to create. Else skip this step
  git --work-tree=/full/path/to/repodir/project1 checkout upstream/master .
  git add .
  git commit -m 'add files from bitbucket master to project1 folder'
  git push
  ```

  **Note:** the `--work-tree` option should use the full path. Assume you clone the TFS repo in `d:\repo`, you should use `--work-tree=d:/repo/repodir/project1`. And also notice if you are using windows OS, you should change `\` to `/` for the path.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time to answer Marina. Very instructive. I think this way the project would be more difficult to maintain... Since it seem you work with TFS maybe you could give me a voice about if I simply could import the existing GIT repo on TFS and then abandone the bitbucket one to continue work with the new TFS as I do now with Bitbucket? I mean, if I have the repo with Git version history type in TFS Can I clone the source on diferent local machines and commit changes to the remote repo like in a Regular Git repository?

Comment: Yes, you can. Local repos are not limited, you only need to have permission  for the TFS git repo. You can clone it in another directoy/machine, and then commit, pull and push etc on the new local repo.

Comment: Thank you for your time Marina, you gave me many useful tips to improve this workflow issues. We implemented the new GIT repo on TFS and plan to abandon the old one, we hope this way the project stay more consistent to deliver the design to the developres :)